# VBA, Transferring of Data from one File to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that:

1. Clears my worksheet from row 12 and onward in Workbook A
2. Opens a new file Workbook B
3. Copys the sheet to my Workbook A. and Close Workbook B
4. Renames sheet in Workbook A
5. Transfers data from New Sheet to another Tab.

This seems to take me 10 minutes+, it is roughly 35k Rows.

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Thanks.

```
    Sub Mainsub()
    
    Worksheets("Main Data").Rows("12:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    'Copy data from the CM File to Template
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Open CM file
    Set MainDataCM = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Input").Range("B16") & Sheets("Input").Range("B19"))
    'Copy main data tab to EPM file workbook
    MainDataCM.Sheets("Main Data").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    'Close CM Comm file
    MainDataCM.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
          
     
    
    Sheets("Main Data (2)").Name = "CM_MainData"
    
    Worksheets("CM_MainData").Visible = False
    
    'Read the CM_MainData tab and copy the required columns in the MainData tab
    Dim k As Long
    k = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A1", Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Debug.Print (k)
    
    i = 12
    j = 2
    
    While j <= k
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("A" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("A" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("B" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("B" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("C" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("C" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("D" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("D" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("E" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("E" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("F" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("F" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("G" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("G" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("H" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("H" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("I" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("I" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("J" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("J" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("K" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("K" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("L" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("L" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("M" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("M" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("N" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("N" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("O" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("O" & j)
        Sheets("Main Data").Range("P" & i) = Sheets("CM_MainData").Range("P" & j)
    
        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
    Wend
    
    Worksheets("Input").Activate
    Worksheets("Input").Select
    
    MsgBox "Step 1 Completed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like instead of transferring, Copying the Data and using ThisWorkbook was able to get the job done easily.

```
Sub Mainsubtwo()

Call Reset
Worksheets("Main Data").Rows("12:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open CM file
Set MainDataCM = Workbooks.Open(Sheets("Input").Range("B16") & Sheets("Input").Range("B19"))

With Sheets("Main Data")
lastrow = Sheets("Main Data").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Main Data").Range("A2:P" & lastrow).Copy
End With
'Paste into this workbook
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Data").Range("A12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


'Close CM file
MainDataCM.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Worksheets("Input").Activate
Worksheets("Input").Select

MsgBox "Step 1 Completed"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy a Range From One File to Another

- `s` - Source (read from), `d` - Destination (written to)
- The code is still far from perfect but may be more educational for you to primarily understand the 'concept' of qualifying the objects:

  ```
  Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' continue using 'wb'
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' continue using 'ws'
  Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("A2") ' continue using 'fCell'
  Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
  Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell) ' continue using 'rg'
  ```

  etc. (it's for a one-column range)
- Copying by assignment is by far the most efficient way to copy values (only):

  ```
  Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Range("A1:D10")
  Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = Range("F1")
  dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count).Value = srg.Value
  ```

  If you additionally do...

  ```
  Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
  Debug.Print drg.Address(0, 0)
  ```

  then the result (the address of the Destination Range) printed in the `Immediate window` will be `F1:I10`.

**The Code**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMainData()
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Retrieve Source Workbook Path and Name.
    Dim swbPath As String, swbName As String
    With dwb.Worksheets("Input")
        swbPath = .Range("B16").Value
        swbName = .Range("B19").Value
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declare the Source Workbook variable.
    Dim swb As Workbook
    
    ' Check if a workbook with the same name as the name of the Source Workbook
    ' is already open. If so, close it saving any changes (or not?).
    On Error Resume Next
    Set swb = Workbooks(swbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not swb Is Nothing Then
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to open the Source Workbook.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath & swbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If swb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The Workbook doesn't exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' If you feel that the previous two code blocks (scenarios)
    ' are not necessary (ridiculous) then replace them with:
    'Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbpath & swbName)
    
    ' The 'Call' keyword is considered deprecated.
    Reset ' Reset what? e.g. 'ResetData' or 'ResetMain' are better names.
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With swb.Worksheets("Main Data")
        Dim sLastRow As Long: sLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set srg = .Range("A2:P" & sLastRow)
    End With
    ' Maybe this would be more appropriate (make sure to test it):
'    With swb.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
'        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
'    End With
    
    ' Calculate the rows count of the (same-sized) ranges.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Using the reference to the Destination First Row Range ('A12:P12')...
    With dwb.Worksheets("Main Data").Range("A12").Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)
        ' Create a reference to the Destination Range.
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = .Resize(rCount)
        ' Copy the values of the Source Range to the Destination Range
        ' by 'assignment'.
        drg.Value = srg.Value
        ' Create a reference to the Destination Clear Range, the range
        ' below the Destination Range.
        Dim dcrg As Range
        Set dcrg = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount)
        ' Clear the contents of the Destination Clear Range
        dcrg.ClearContents
    End With
    
    ' Save and close.
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'dwb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Main data copied."

End Sub
```